# How to access every SerialName associated with each enum constant in an enum class?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have a data class that I want to make serializable

```
data class ClassTemp (
    val str: String,
    val tmp: Temp,
)
```

```
@Serializable
enum class Temp {
    @SerialName("Serial Name - 1")
    S1,
    @SerialName("Serial Name - 2")
    S2
}
```

Example JSON that I want to deserialize and it's corresponding ClassTemp object

```json
{
    "str": "Some String",
    "tmp": "Serial Name - 1",
}
```

```
ClassTemp(
    str: "Some String"
    tmp: Temp.S1
)
```

Now the problem is not specifically about serializing and deserializing since that's working fine. It's just that for the given `enum class Temp` How would I get all the SerialNames that are in it?

```
[ "Serial Name - 1", "Serial Name - 2" ]
```

Comment: You wrote class `Temp` yourself and know all SerialNames. You can even create a list of String constants. I read https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums, there are some methods to serialize enum class, but they hardly can be used here. There is a problem that when you will change `Temp`, string constants in another class should also be changed.

Comment: You could have a look whether you can find anything in the serial descriptor. That may work without reflection as per the current answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the annotation values of each enum field:

```
val serialNames = Temp.values().map { 
  Temp::class.java.getField(it.name).getAnnotation(SerialName::class.java)?.value 
}
```

Comment: can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)